# JSF dataTable with radio buttons

Tags: jsf, datatable, radio-button

I want to create a web page using JSF with the following table:

```
Item 1 | ( ) good ( ) ok ( ) bad
Item 2 | ( ) good ( ) ok ( ) bad
Item 3 | ( ) good ( ) ok ( ) bad
[…]
```

After a radio button has been checked, I immediately want to submit and process the rating. The current code for the dataTable looks as follows:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" var="item">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.title}"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <h:form>
        <h:selectOneRadio id="rate" value="#{bean.rate}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="good" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="ok" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="-1" itemLabel="bad" />
            <f:ajax event="click" execute="rate" />
        </h:selectOneRadio>
        </h:form>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

The problem I am now facing: I need to determine, which item was actually rated. Can somebody give me a hint how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose among several techniques. For example, you could use a `Map` in your bean

`<h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.ratePerItem[item]}"`

`Map<ItemClass, Integer> ratePerItem;`

That way you must walk through the map looking for values. A simpler approach for your needs might be using a `h:inputHidden` which stores the item.

Or, maybe better, `f:setPropertyActionListener`. It depends on what you exactly want.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried the Map approach, which works, but I cannot directly access, *which* Item was rated, right? The approach with inputHidden sounds better for me; can you go a bit more into detail? I add the following to my markup: `<h:inputHidden id="currentItem" name="currentItem" value="#{item}" />`, but how to access the item in the bean?

Comment: Sorry, thought I solved the problem, but I was wrong :( I have the item in the hidden input now, but how can I obtain the item in the bean?

Comment: With the Map approach you must iterate looking for true values. In fact this is useful for multiple selection.

Comment: h:inputHidden would probably force you to convert to String and iterate. Give `Map` approach a try. Why would you not want to use it?

Comment: The problem with the Map is, that I cannot figure out, which of the items was currently clicked when the event was triggered, right? Or am I understanding wrong?

Comment: Well, it depends on the way your interaction works and what are your expectations. Take a look at `f:setPropertyActionListener`, it might be a much better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Adding "rate" property to the Item class will help you determine easily which Item is rated.

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="rate" value="#{bean.rate}"
            <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="good" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="ok" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="-1" itemLabel="bad" />
            <f:ajax event="click" execute="rate" />
        </h:selectOneRadio>
```

Change the above code to

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="rate" value="#{item.rate}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="good" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="ok" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="-1" itemLabel="bad" />
            <f:ajax event="click" execute="rate" />
        </h:selectOneRadio>
```

Comment: Surely this will technically work, but in this particular use case, the "rate" is not supposed to be tight-coupled to a specific "item" applicationwide, simply because it depends on the currently logged-in user! It makes designtechnically sense to separate it from the "item" as one-to-many relationship. In other words, this answer is **not** the right solution to OP's particular use case.